# toco_from_protos: command not found

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm using this following link to convert my Tensorflow model to tf lite model
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api, In here i'm following instruction for 'Exporting a GraphDef from file'
But i'm getting following error

```
    "TOCO failed. See console for info.\n%s\n%s\n" % (stdout, stderr))
     tensorflow.lite.python.convert.ConverterError: TOCO failed. See console for info.
    /bin/sh: toco_from_protos: command not found
```

I've installed latest tensorflow v1.13.1

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: No not really, the issue is with setting path, it cannot find path on my machine, tried to set path but didn't work, got it converted from different machine

Comment: Would you be so nice to give me a hint on how to convert? This problem is driving me nuts :(

Comment: @lelloman converted on one of my colleagues machine, somehow his tensorflow was in working condition, you can use a different machine or find someone who has not updated form old version

Comment: Thanks, in the end I solved by using a docker image, now that I tried it I don't think I'll ever install tensorflow on a system again

Answer (score 4):

### The problem

Tensorflow calls to a specific binary file to convert the .pb file (stored by protobuf) in a tflite model. The binary file is 'toco_from_protos', and the error message suggests that the shell interpreter ('/bin/sh' in this case) is not able to find the binary file ('toco_from_proto').

You need to include the path to 'toco_from_proto' file in the PATH environment variable.

### How to do this

First, check if the file exists. You can use the command 'locate' for example:

```
$ locate toco_from_proto
/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/bin/toco_from_protos
/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/toco/python/toco_from_protos.py
/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/toco/python/__pycache__/toco_from_protos.cpython-36.pyc
```

In my case, I am using Anaconda to manage the environments. Thus, the binary is in the binary path ('bin' folder) of the environment container ('tensorflow' in this case).

To ensure the correct execution of the binary, include the path to 'toco_from_protos' file inside PATH environment variable. If you are using a Linux based system, you can do something like:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/bin
```

If you are using an IDE program (e.g. Pycharm), you can call the IDE run script using the same console you used to export the PATH variable. For example:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/bin
$ /opt/pycharm-community-2018.1.4/bin/pycharm.sh
```

The new PATH value change remains only in that console window, so if you want to make the change persistent, include the export sentence inside '~/.bashrc' file.

Comment: hi goe, it seems that even after adding the virtualenv bin to the $PATH variable, Tensorflow ( 2.0 ) is not able to find toco_from_protos, would you know what is going on?

Comment: I have not tested Tensorflow 2.0, so I am not sure how it works with the paths, sorry. Check if the compilation of the toco_from_protos binary you are pointing to is compatible with the Tensorflow library you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved by using an official docker image, host machine has a fresh Ubuntu 18.04.

```
docker run --runtime=nvidia -v /path/to/my/project:/mapped/docker/path -it tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu bash
```

Then run the conversion script inside docker:

```
model = load_model() # keras model
output_names = [node.op.name for node in model.outputs]
input_names = [node.op.name for node in model.inputs]
with tf.keras.backend.get_session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    frozen_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, sess.graph_def, output_names)
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_session(sess, model.inputs, model.outputs)
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
    open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

At the time of writing `tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu` is version `1.13.1`

Comment: What if we want a local install via Pip instead of virtual Docker image?

Answer (score 1):

I too got same error log in tensorflow 1.14. For me issue was not in converter, it was was related to path not getting resolved.

On running this before Python script, it worked for me
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin